# SWT CoolBar ToolBar right position

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have the following code:

```
@Override
protected CoolBarManager createCoolBarManager(int style) {
    CoolBarManager coolBarManager = new CoolBarManager(style);
    coolBarManager.setLockLayout(true);
    ToolBarManager toolbarAtendimento = new ToolBarManager();
    toolbarAtendimento.add(incluirAtendimentosAction);
    toolbarAtendimento.add(incluirClientesAction);
    toolbarAtendimento.add(listarAtendimentosAction);
    toolbarAtendimento.add(listarClientesAction);
    toolbarAtendimento.add(sincronizarAtendimentosAction);
    toolbarAtendimento.add(visualizarRelatSincronizacaoAction);
    coolBarManager.add(toolbarAtendimento);
    return coolBarManager;
}
```

I am trying to position the toolbar buttons in the righ. But `SWT.RIGHT` style does nothing.

I found the following link:
[Positioning Toolbars in Eclipse/RCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759600/positioning-toolbars-in-eclipse-rcp)

This is the only way? My platform is Linux.

Comment: `SWT.RIGHT` for `ToolBar` will only influence the alignment of the text within the items, not the alignment of the whole `ToolBar`. You can't align it to the right.

Comment: Thanks baz! I'll try to build a personalized control.

Comment: If you find a suitable solution, please post it here as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to right align items in a toolbar by explicitly changing its layout:

```
GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().align(SWT.END, SWT.CENTER).grab(true, false).applyTo(toolBar);
```

see [SWT: How to right align items in a toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132257/swt-how-to-right-align-items-in-a-toolbar)

Comment: though, I have not tested it with a Coolbar