# SWT: How to right align items in a toolbar

Tags: java, swt, jface

In a pure SWT/JFace application, I need to align toolbar items to the right.
I first tried to use the SWT.RIGHT style when creating the Toolbar but items are still left aligned.
After some investigations, I found out that SWT.RIGHT is used for the alignment of text within an item not for the alignment of the items on the toolbar.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to right align items in a toolbar by explicitly changing its layout:

```
GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().align(SWT.END, SWT.CENTER).grab(true, false).applyTo(toolBar);
```

Source: http://codifyit.blogspot.com/2010/04/eclipse-tips-part-2.html

Comment: I'm trying to algin a search box in my toolbar to the right while keeping everything else to the left however I don't seem to be able to achieve this behavior using this code snippet. How would I go about to align one ToolbarItem to the right? I applied above code to my toolbar but I'm not sure how to make the searchbox/ToolbarItem to be affected.

Edit: It seems to semi work when using a not using OS X unified toolbar however I do not wish to align everything to the right.

Comment: I see what you are trying to achieve, unfortunately, I don't have an out-of-the-box solution. Maybe would it be possible by implementing some kind of 'Spacer' component whose width would be computed based on toolbar's content and would take as much as possible and then 'push' component to the end of the toolbar. See what I mean ?